Sitecore SolrCloud: Main alias not updating after index rebuild
I'm using Sitecore SolrCloud, and I have encountered an issue with the index rebuild process. Here's what happened:
I inadvertently deleted index records from both the main and rebuild aliases in my Solr instance.
After rebuilding the indexes from the Sitecore Indexing Manager, the data is being updated in the rebuild alias as expected, but the main alias is not being updated.
I have tried copying the data folder from the rebuild alias to the main alias, but the main alias still doesn't show the updated data.
My questions are:
How can I resolve this issue and ensure that the main alias gets updated with the rebuilt index data?
When does the swap between the main and rebuild aliases happen after a full index rebuild in SolrCloud?
Is there a way to see or monitor the swapping process during the index rebuild?
I would appreciate any insights or suggestions from the community on how to resolve this issue and better understand the index rebuild process in Sitecore SolrCloud.

Harish, After deleting the index records, how many times did you run the rebuild indexes?

2 times I did trigger index rebuild.

Can you share an example of how sitecore_master_index looks like in showconfig?

did I get it right that: after you have triggered reindex you still see the old data on your website?

Check the ContentSearch.Solr.EnforceAliasCreation setting and make sure it's true on the machine having the indexing role (only one machine!) and that it's false on all other roles. After a rebuild, the aliases should be swapped. Also check the Properties table in the Core database and check the values of *_SOLR_ACTIVE_COLLECTION and *_SOLR_REBUILD_COLLECTION. The should swap after a rebuild and they should align with the aliases in place in SolrCloud. This is at least a good start when finding where things goes wrong.
